# Using Webpack 5 - How to reference files with a [contenthash] substitution in html when using a server-side templating engine?

Tags: javascript, webpack, handlebars.js, webpack-5, templating-engine

**When using**: `copy-webpack-plugin`

**And specifying `to:` as**: `'images/[name].[contenthash][ext]'`

How do you reference these files in your templates without using
`html-webpack-plugin` or `handlebars-loader`?

I have solved this with the following solution:

```
/**
 * Create a new plugin class.
 */
const StoreAssetsInfoKeysPlugin = class StoreAssetsInfoKeysPlugin {
  /**
   * Define `apply` as its prototype method.
   * @param hooks
   */
  apply({ hooks }) {
    /**
     * Using the 'afterCompile' hook:
     * Use the 'assetsInfo' Map which contains the output of all asset paths,
     * construct an array containing all these paths,
     * then write an 'assets.json' file somewhere in your project.
     */
    hooks.afterCompile.tapAsync('StoreAssetsInfoKeysPlugin', ({ assetsInfo }, callback) => {
      fs.writeFileSync('/path/to/assets.json', JSON
        .stringify(Array
          .from(assetsInfo.entries())
          .map(([key]) => `/assets/${key}`)));

      callback();
    });
  }
};
```

```
/**
 * The Webpack configuration for this
 * example looks like this.
 */
export default {
  plugins: [
    new StoreAssetsInfoKeysPlugin(),
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [{
        from: '/path/to/images/*',
        to: 'images/[name].[contenthash][ext]',
      }],
    }),
  ],
};
```

```
/**
 * Create a helper function which will find the
 * correct path from the 'assets.json'
 */
export const getAssetPath = function getAssetPath(directory, filename, ext) {
  return JSON
    .parse(fs.readFileSync('/path/to/assets.json'))
    .find((value) => value
      .match(`^.*?\\b${directory}\\b.*?\\b${filename}\\b.*?\\.${ext}\\b.*?$`));
};
```

```
/**
 * Then use the helper function within your
 * server-side templating engine:
 */
getAssetPath('images', 'my-image', 'svg');
```

Is this a suitable solution?

This was my first solution to achieve obtaining the file names with a `[contenthash]` substitution in server-side templates.

I'm new to Webpack so any thoughts on this approach would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I try to define the goal in detail:

1. we have a template file (e.g. index.hbs)
2. in the source template file should be referenced `source files` of scripts, styles, images, and other assets
3. in the processed template file should be hashed `output filenames` containing `contenthash`
4. the template file must not be rendered into HTML, to use the template by server-side rendering

Is the goal correct?

If yes, then you can use one powerful "html-bundler-webpack-plugin" without `html-webpack-plugin`, `handlebars-loader`, `copy-webpack-plugin`.

For example, there is the file structure of the example:

```
src/views/index.hbs
src/scss/styles.scss
src/js/main.js
src/images/picture.png

dist/ <= output directory for processed files
```

There is source template file `src/views/index.hbs` (or other HTML file):

```html
<html>
<head>
  <!-- source files with path relative to the template file -->
  <link href="../scss/styles.scss" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="../js/main.js" defer="defer"></script>
</head>
<body>
  {{> header }}
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  
  <!-- source image file with path relative to the template file -->
  <img src="../images/picture.png">

  {{> footer }}
</body>
</html>
```

The *webpack.config.js*:

```js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlBundlerPlugin = require('html-bundler-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'), // output path for processed files
  },,
  plugins: [
    new HtmlBundlerPlugin({
      entry: {
        // define templates here
        // the key is output file path w/o extension, e.g.:
        index: 'src/views/index.hbs', // => dist/index.hbs
      },
      js: {
        // output filename of compiled JavaScript
        filename: 'js/[name].[contenthash:8].js',
      },
      css: {
        // output filename of extracted CSS
        filename: 'css/[name].[contenthash:8].css',
      },
      // defaults used Eta (ESJ like) template engine to render into HTML
      // if you will render .hbs to .html, then define as `handlebars`
      preprocessor: false, // <= disable rendering into HTML to keep original template content
    }),
  ],

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(scss)$/,
        use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ico|png|jp?g|svg)/,
        type: 'asset/resource',
        generator: {
          // output filename of images
          filename: 'img/[name].[hash:8][ext]',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

If you will keep original template content and only replace source asset files with their hashed output filenames, then disable the rendering using the `preprocessor: false` plugin option.

The processed (not rendered to html) template will be looks like:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <!-- output filenames relative to the dist/ directory -->
  <link href="css/styles.0f23efdf.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="js/main.5317c1f6.js" defer="defer"></script>
</head>
<body>
  {{> header }}
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>

  <!-- output filenames relative to the dist/ directory -->
  <img src="img/picture.7b396424.png" />

  {{> footer }}
</body>
</html>
```

If you will render any template into HTML, you can use one of supported templating engines "out of the box":  [Eta](https://github.com/webdiscus/html-bundler-webpack-plugin#using-template-eta), [EJS](https://github.com/webdiscus/html-bundler-webpack-plugin#using-template-ejs), [Handlebars](https://github.com/webdiscus/html-bundler-webpack-plugin#using-template-handlebars), [Nunjucks](https://github.com/webdiscus/html-bundler-webpack-plugin#using-template-nunjucks), [LiquidJS](https://github.com/webdiscus/html-bundler-webpack-plugin#using-template-liquidjs).

The config of the plugin to render handlebars template to HTML:

```js
  new HtmlBundlerPlugin({
      entry: {
        // define templates here
        // the key is output file path w/o extension, e.g.:
        index: 'src/views/index.hbs', // => dist/index.html
      },
      js: {
        // output filename of compiled JavaScript
        filename: 'js/[name].[contenthash:8].js',
      },
      css: {
        // output filename of extracted CSS
        filename: 'css/[name].[contenthash:8].css',
      },
      // specify the `handlebars` template engine
      preprocessor: 'handlebars',
      // define handlebars options
      preprocessorOptions: {
        partials: ['src/views/partials'],
      },
    })
```

The rendered HTML:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <!-- output filenames relative to the dist/ directory -->
  <link href="css/styles.0f23efdf.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="js/main.5317c1f6.js" defer="defer"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="header">html of your header partials</div>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>

  <!-- output filenames relative to the dist/ directory -->
  <img src="img/picture.7b396424.png" />

  <div class="footer">html of your footer partials</div>
</body>
</html>
```